# How can I return SQL results that are ONLY about specific attributes?

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue:
ID    AttributeValueID
101   1319
101   1320
101   1344
101   1345
102   1319
102   1320
102   1321
102   1336
103   1320
103   1336
```

I have another table that groups these AttributeValueIDs by type:

```
TBL_AttributeValues:
AttributeValueID    AttributeTypeID
1319                1
1320                1
1321                1
1336                2
1344                3 
1345                3
```

I have a third table that gives information about each ID from the first table:

```
TBL_Aids:
ID     Title                Author       etc.
101    Aid About Spiders    John Doe
102    Aid About Mites      Jane Doe 
103    Aid About Beetles    Joe Schmo
```

I would like to return results of IDs (and information about them, like the Title, Author, etc.) that contain ONLY AttributeValueIDs 1319 OR (inclusive) 1320, within AttributeTypeID=1.  So I would hope to return 101 because it only has 1319 and 1320 for AttributeType 1, and also 103 because it has only 1320 for AttributeType 1.  I would not want to return 102 because although it has 1319 and 1320, it also has 1321, which is of AttributeType 1 as well.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, c.AttributeTypeID, 
COUNT(b.AttributeValueID)AS Total
FROM TBL_Aids as a,
REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue as b,
TBL_AttributeValues as c
WHERE a.ID=b.AidID
AND b.AttributeValueID=c.ID
AND a.Status=2
AND AttributeTypeID=1
AND (b.AttributeValueID=1319
OR b.AttributeValueID=1320)
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Title,
c.AttributeTypeID
HAVING COUNT(b.AttributeValueID) <= 2
```

But it still returns 102 as a result, because it has already limited by 1319 and 1320 and is counting that total instead of the overall total of AttributeValueIDs for Type 1.  Do I need some sort of subquery to accomplish this?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue a
        WHERE   attributeValueId IN (1319, 1320)
        ) q
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    (
                SELECT  AttributeValueID
                FROM    TBL_AttributeValues
                WHERE   AttributeTypeID = 1
                        AND AttributeValueID NOT IN (1319, 1320)
                ) t
        JOIN    REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue a
        ON      a.id = q.id
                AND a.AttributeValueID = t.AttributeValueID
        )
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thank you so much.  I ended up adding to this to get the final information I wanted, but I never could have done it without your help.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
FROM REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue A
WHERE A.AttributeValueID IN
(
    SELECT AttributeValueID
    FROM TBL_AttributeValues
    WHERE AttributeValueID IN (1319, 1320) AND AttributeTypeID=1
)
AND A.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT A.ID
    FROM REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue A
    WHERE A.AttributeValueID IN
    (
        SELECT AttributeValueID
        FROM TBL_AttributeValues
        WHERE AttributeValueID NOT IN (1319, 1320)  AND AttributeTypeID=1
    )
)
```

Comment: I must not have explained that part very well, sorry.  I should have explained the 3rd table and labeled them, as they are now in my edits above.  "WHERE A.AttributeValueID IN" is not correct because AttributeValueID is not in TBL_Aids.  Also, AttributeTypeID is not in AttributeValueIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to limit your ids.  Somewhere in your where clause, you can include something like:

```
where id in (select distinct av.id
             from AttributeValueType avt join
                  AttributeValue av
                   on avt.AttributeValueId = av.AttributeValueId
             where avt.AttributeValueId in (1319, 1320) and avt.AttributeTypeID = 1
            )
```

If you want only when those two attributes are there, try this:

```
Where id in (
    Select av.id
    From AttributeValueType avt join
         AttributeValue av
         on avt.AttributeValueId = av.AttributeValueId
    Group by av.id
    Having max(case when avt.AttributeValueId in (1319, 1320) and avt.AttributeTypeID = 1 then 0 else 1)=0
    Having max(case when
```

Comment: Running this subquery on its own returns results that have other AttributeValueIDs other than 1319 and 1320 (that are still of AttributeValueTypeID = 1).  Should that be happening?

Comment: Bummer.  That seemed like a good idea, but it's returning 0 results.  Thanks for trying again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add 'NOT EXISTS' in some way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM TBL_Aids x
WHERE AttributeValueID IN
(
    SELECT AttributeValueID
    FROM AttributeValueIDs
    WHERE AttributeValueID IN (1319, 1320) AND AttributeTypeID=1
) AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM AttributeValueIDs a
    WHERE a.AttributeValueID NOT IN (1319, 1320) AND a.AttributeTypeID=1
    AND a.AttributeValueIDs = x.AttributeValueIDs
)
```

Comment: "Not exists" seems like a good idea, but I'm still confused as to how this would work.  AttributeValueID should be selected from REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue I believe, whereas AttributeTypeID is only in TBL_AttributeValues.  Wouldn't there need to be some other joins going on here to relate the two?

Comment: It would work because it would reject rows where the AttributeTypeID is of the given type but AttributeValueID not of the given list.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it better.  I edited my question above to include the other table that I need to grab information from.  AttributeValueID is not in TBL_Aids, and AttributeTypeID is not in what you called AttributeValueIDs (I assumed you meant REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue?)

Comment: No problem. I tried to edit the answer to use the right table names, but then it got too complicated for me. Quassnoi got it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue twice to ensure that *two* rows exist

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, c.AttributeTypeID, 2 AS Total
FROM TBL_Aids a
join REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue b on a.ID=b.AidID and b.AttributeValueID = 1319
join REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue b2 on a.ID=b2.AidID and b2.AttributeValueID = 1320
join TBL_AttributeValues c on b.AttributeValueID=c.ID
WHERE a.Status=2
AND AttributeTypeID=1;
```

Also not that if you know what values you have, you know how many there are, so it's a literal `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue twice to ensure that *two* rows exist

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, c.AttributeTypeID, 2 AS Total
FROM TBL_Aids a
join REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue b on a.ID=b.AidID and b.AttributeValueID = 1319
join REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue b2 on a.ID=b2.AidID and b2.AttributeValueID = 1320
join TBL_AttributeValues c on b.AttributeValueID=c.ID
WHERE a.Status=2
AND AttributeTypeID=1;
```

Note that I've converted your query to the more modern "join" syntax. I suggest you learn it.

Also note that if you know what values you have, you know how many there are, so it's a literal `2`.

Comment: This isn't quite right but seemed to make sense to me.  It is only returning about 100 results, but I'm estimating the result set to be closer to 700.  Also and more importantly, the results are inaccurate.  They do have both attribute values 1319 and 1320, but also have other attribute values as well.  Yeah, I haven't used join much because I didn't see the benefit of it over the way I used.  If it worked in this instance, I'd be convinced!  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Quassnoi:

```
    SELECT ID, Title, Author
    FROM TBL_Aids X
    JOIN (
    SELECT AidID
    FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT AidID
            FROM    REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue a
            WHERE   AttributeValueID IN (1319, 1320)
            ) q
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (
            SELECT  AidID
            FROM    (
                    SELECT  ID
                    FROM    TBL_AttributeValues
                    WHERE   AttributeTypeID = 1
                            AND ID NOT IN (1319, 1320)
                    ) t
            JOIN    REL_Aid_To_AttributeValue a
            ON      a.AidID = q.AidID
                    AND a.AttributeValueID = t.ID
            ))
    Y ON X.ID=Y.AidID
    WHERE Status=2
```